# iOS voice over issue in safari browser

Tags: ios, html, safari, accessibility, voice

I am trying to use voice over in my web page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <form action="demo_form.asp">
                First name: <input type="text" name="fname" tabindex="1"><br>
                Second name: <input type="text" name="sname" tabindex="2"><br>
                Third name: <input type="text" name="tname" tabindex="3"><br>
                Last name: <input type="text" name="lhan" tabindex="4"><br>
               <input type="submit" value="Submit">
           </form>
       </body>
   </html>
```

If I open this page in a Iphone, First it reads " First name ".

I just clicked on "fname" textbox to enter any text then press the "Done" button of keypad.
Keypad disappears and then it automatically focus the "Third Name" textbox and read the text.

This behavior is not consistent.

Is it expected behavior?
How can I give order to the voice control ? (tabindex)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using **`tabindex`** attribute? Most of the time, they're unnecessary - especially strictly positive values that will mess with natural tab order when browsers are in fact already doing fine with normal HTML code with links and form elements.
My advice: remove any `tabindex` attribute from your code, except for very special cases like a comment form in a forum where you want to type text into a textarea, then 1 or 2 tab, Enter and you're submitting your message regardless of buttons for inserting bbCode that could be placed between the textarea and the submit button.
At the slightest change in HTML code of your templates, the presence of `tabindex` will be forgotten, they won't be updated and it will break the tab order.
Relevant WCAG 2.0 Techniques:

- [F44: Failure (...) due to using tabindex to create a tab order that does not preserve meaning and operability](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/F44.html)
- [H4: Creating a logical tab order through links, form controls, and objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H4.html)
- other Techniques are linked from the ones above

Now about the rest of the code: labels of a form elements should be tagged with... **`label`** elements. Associating each `label` element to its respective form element (any `input` type - except `submit`, `image` and `button` one - and also any `select` and `textarea`) is done via identical values of `for` and `id` attributes:

```
<label for="blah">My label</label><textarea id="blah"></textarea>
```

**[JSFiddle of your code corrected](http://jsfiddle.net/5eTqD/)**

- each form element and label is in its own paragraph element
- label is added (around each form element so message of error or hint on the right of form element or below it can still be in the label
- unique id added to each form element (I took the same value as `name` but whatever is a valid id is OK)
- `for` attribute added to label with identical value as each id above

**HTML code**

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
    <p>
        <label for="fname">First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="sname">Second name: <input type="text" name="sname" id="sname"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="tname">Third name: <input type="text" name="tname" id="tname"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lhan">Last name: <input type="text" name="lhan" id="lhan"></label>
    </p>
    <p class="w300p txtright">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

Relevant WCAG 2.0 Techniques:

- [H44: Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H44.html)
- [G131: Providing descriptive labels](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G131.html)
- [F17: Failure (...) due to insufficient information in DOM to determine one-to-one relationships (e.g., between labels with same id) in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/F17.html)
- [F86: Failure (...) due to not providing names for each part of a multi-part form field, such as a US telephone number](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/F86.html)

**The 5 seconds test** to determine if `label` elements and `for` / `id` pairs are coded with accessibility in mind or not:

- take a mouse
- click on each text that should be a label right before or after a form element. Cursor/caret/focus must go into the form element next to it

This is a 10 second test on tablets and smartphones because tap is a bit slower ^^